# HTML5 Canvas Parsing image into tileset while preserving transparency

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, transparency

I'm trying to import a Tiled Map Editor JSON file into my HTML5 canvas game but I'm having trouble with separating out the tileset image into separate images while preserving the transparency.

Currently I'm using a temporary canvas element and the `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` functions to grab specific parts of the tileset image and push the separate "tile" image into an array.

I understand that `putImageData()` renders the Image Data pixel by pixel, thus filling the transparent pixels with the background color of the page, but I can't figure out exactly how to fix this.

You can see the problem here:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
(function() {

var tilesets = [];
var tiles = [];
tiles.push(null);

tmxJSON = {

    map: null,

    load: function(jsonFile) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Call function for next step in process
                tmxJSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", jsonFile, true);
        xhr.send();
    },

    parse: function(json) {
        map = eval("(" + json + ")");

        tmxJSON.loadTilesetImages();

    },

    loadTilesetImages: function() {

        var successCount = 0;
        var errorCount = 0;

        for (var ts = 0; ts < map.tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener("load", function() {
                successCount++;
                if (successCount + errorCount == map.tilesets.length) {
                    tmxJSON.separateTiles();
                }
            });
            image.addEventListener("error", function() {
                errorCount++;
                alert("error loading: " + map.tilesets[ts].image);
            });
            image.src = map.tilesets[ts].image;

            tilesets.push(image);

        }


    },

    separateTiles: function() {

        for (var ts = 0; ts < tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var tileCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var tileContext = tileCanvas.getContext("2d");

            tileCanvas.width = tilesets[ts].width;
            tileCanvas.height = tilesets[ts].height;

            tileContext.drawImage(tilesets[ts], 0, 0);

            var nTilesX = tilesets[ts].width / map.tilewidth;
            var nTilesY = tilesets[ts].height / map.tileheight;

            for (ty = 0; ty < nTilesY; ty++) {
                for (tx = 0; tx < nTilesX; tx++) {
                    var x = tx * map.tilewidth;
                    var y = ty * map.tileheight;

                    var imageData = tileContext.getImageData(x, y, map.tilewidth, map.tileheight);

                    tiles.push(imageData);
                }
            }
        }
        tmxJSON.drawTiles();
    },

    drawTiles: function() {

        for (var l = 0; l < map.layers.length; l++) {
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            if (map.layers[l].type === "tilelayer") {
                for (var d = 0; d < map.layers[l].data.length; d++) {

                    if (d % map.width == 0 && d != 0) {
                        y += map.tileheight;
                        x = 0;
                    }


                    if (map.layers[l].data[d] != 0) {
                        context.putImageData(tiles[map.layers[l].data[d]], x, y);
                    }
                    x += map.tilewidth;
                }

            }
        }

    }
};

}());
```

EDIT: Alright I've taken the advice of Mokosha and changed the putImageData to drawImage using a separate canvas, but I'm coming up with this error:

```
GET http://storrdev.com/tmxJSON/[object%20HTMLCanvasElement] 404 (Not Found)
```

This is something I was running into before when I tried something like this... and the reason I abandoned it. What is happening? I printed all the x and y coordinates for each tile and they all appear to load just fine until the last one... I'm so confused!

Here's the updated code:

```
(function() {

var tilesets = [];
var tiles = [];
tiles.push(null);

tmxJSON = {

    map: null,

    load: function(jsonFile) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Call function for next step in process
                tmxJSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", jsonFile, true);
        xhr.send();
    },

    parse: function(json) {
        map = eval("(" + json + ")");

        tmxJSON.loadTilesetImages();

    },

    loadTilesetImages: function() {

        var successCount = 0;
        var errorCount = 0;

        for (var ts = 0; ts < map.tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener("load", function() {
                successCount++;
                if (successCount + errorCount == map.tilesets.length) {
                    tmxJSON.separateTiles();
                }
            });
            image.addEventListener("error", function() {
                errorCount++;
                alert("error loading: " + map.tilesets[ts].image);
            });
            image.src = map.tilesets[ts].image;

            tilesets.push(image);

        }


    },

    separateTiles: function() {

        for (var ts = 0; ts < tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var tileCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var tileContext = tileCanvas.getContext("2d");

            tileCanvas.width = map.tilewidth;
            tileCanvas.height = map.tileheight;

            var nTilesX = tilesets[ts].width / map.tilewidth;
            var nTilesY = tilesets[ts].height / map.tileheight;

            for (ty = 0; ty < nTilesY; ty++) {
                for (tx = 0; tx < nTilesX; tx++) {
                    var x = tx * map.tilewidth;
                    var y = ty * map.tileheight;

                    tileContext.drawImage(tilesets[ts], -x, -y);

                    //var imageData = tileContext.getImageData(x, y, map.tilewidth, map.tileheight);\

                    console.log(x + ", " + y);

                    var tile = new Image();
                    tile.src = tileCanvas;

                    tiles.push(tile);
                }
            }
        }
        tmxJSON.drawTiles();
    },

    drawTiles: function() {

        for (var l = 0; l < map.layers.length; l++) {
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            if (map.layers[l].type === "tilelayer") {
                for (var d = 0; d < map.layers[l].data.length; d++) {

                    if (d % map.width == 0 && d != 0) {
                        y += map.tileheight;
                        x = 0;
                    }


                    if (map.layers[l].data[d] != 0) {
                        context.drawImage(tiles[map.layers[l].data[d]], x, y);
                    }
                    x += map.tilewidth;
                }

            }
        }

    }
};

}());
```

Comment: `putImageData` doesn't "render" in the sense that you're thinking of. It literally copies the pixels into the given rendering context. Depending on what you're trying to do, you probably want to use `drawImage` to render each tile directly into the context

Comment: Thanks! Mokosha I've implemented your changes but came up with an error I can't figure out. I've updated my question with the new code and error if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've found the solution to my problem.

Following Mokosha's advice was the way to go, but in my edit I only went halfway. I found out that when creating an Image() from a separate canvas you need to use the canvas method .toDataURL("image/png");

Here's the website I used to figure that part out: http://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image

You can see my correct code below:

```
(function() {

var tilesets = [];
var tiles = [];
tiles.push(null);

tmxJSON = {

    map: null,

    load: function(jsonFile) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Call function for next step in process
                tmxJSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", jsonFile, true);
        xhr.send();
    },

    parse: function(json) {
        map = eval("(" + json + ")");

        tmxJSON.loadTilesetImages();

    },

    loadTilesetImages: function() {

        var successCount = 0;
        var errorCount = 0;

        for (var ts = 0; ts < map.tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener("load", function() {
                successCount++;
                if (successCount + errorCount == map.tilesets.length) {
                    tmxJSON.separateTiles();
                }
            });
            image.addEventListener("error", function() {
                errorCount++;
                alert("error loading: " + map.tilesets[ts].image);
            });
            image.src = map.tilesets[ts].image;

            tilesets.push(image);

        }


    },

    separateTiles: function() {

        var successCount = 0;

        for (var ts = 0; ts < tilesets.length; ts++) {

            var nTilesX = tilesets[ts].width / map.tilewidth;
            var nTilesY = tilesets[ts].height / map.tileheight;

            for (ty = 0; ty < nTilesY; ty++) {
                for (tx = 0; tx < nTilesX; tx++) {
                    var tileCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    var tileContext = tileCanvas.getContext("2d");

                    tileCanvas.width = map.tilewidth;
                    tileCanvas.height = map.tileheight;

                    var x = tx * map.tilewidth;
                    var y = ty * map.tileheight;

                    tileContext.drawImage(tilesets[ts], -x, -y);

                    var tile = new Image();
                    tile.src = tileCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                    tiles.push(tile);
                }
            }
        }
        tmxJSON.drawTiles();
    },

    drawTiles: function() {

        for (var l = 0; l < map.layers.length; l++) {
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            if (map.layers[l].type === "tilelayer") {
                for (var d = 0; d < map.layers[l].data.length; d++) {

                    if (d % map.width == 0 && d != 0) {
                        y += map.tileheight;
                        x = 0;
                    }


                    if (map.layers[l].data[d] != 0) {
                        context.drawImage(tiles[map.layers[l].data[d]], x, y);
                    }
                    x += map.tilewidth;
                }

            }
        }

    }
};

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but I assume you have a "sprite sheet" and you're trying to cut out the individual sprites into their own Image objects to later draw on a canvas using a 2d context's drawImage method.

Assuming that's what you want to do, it's not necessary. I've implemented animation using sprite-sheets in my game and I didn't copy any of the images, I just draw them directly from the sheet using drawImage.